# IF statements and bool return values

Tags: c#

I have created a method called CheckValidity which returns a bool and receives a file name as a string.
I'm using string method EndsWith to check if the value of the file name ends with *.txt*.
If it does not end with *.txt* i want to display a messagebox. if it does I want to enable and disable a few button on the windows form.
I'm new to c# programming so any help would be great.

**Will the (CheckValidity(ofd.FileName))run only if the return is true, or will it run as long as it receives any bool return?**

please see the code below.

```
private void openFileButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
     ofd.InitialDirectory = (@"C:\");
     ofd.Filter = ("calender|.txt");
     ofd.FileName = "calender.txt";
     ofd.CheckFileExists = false;
     ofd.ShowDialog();

  if (CheckValidity(ofd.FileName))
     {
        enterButton.Enabled = true;
        closeFileButton.Enabled = true;
        openFileButton.Enabled = false;
     }

   }

private static bool CheckValidity(string fileName)
  {

     if (fileName.EndsWith(".txt"))

        return true;

     else
           MessageBox.Show(" Application expects a Text File ");

     return false;

  }
```

Comment: Your code already does what you are asking. The button enable block will execute if `CheckValidity` returns true, and will not if it returns false. What are you asking? Also, don't put tags in your title

Comment: fyi http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Looks good to me. Did you run this?

Comment: yes it works but will the (CheckValidity(ofd.FileName))run only if the return is true, or will it run as long as it receives any bool return?

Comment: Yes it will only return true if that is what is returned (as my comment and the answer state). The answer is a good explanation, make sure you understand it.

Comment: Sorry thanks very much, I was just afraid that i was overlooking something because it seemed too simple its part of a college assignment. Thanks again.

Comment: @Tom Consider reading the `if` statement piece of the C# 5 specification. It will make it pretty clear how it works (it is a bit technical, but at least its authoritative).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I. Check whether the return of the CheckValidity method is true
> or false? Use different if statements depending on the result of the
> bool value returned?
>
> will the (CheckValidity(ofd.FileName)) run only if the return is true,
> or will it run as long as it receives any bool return

You already have the right idea. A bool can hold true or false. When you check the return value of a bool, you are checking for true-ness, not *any bool return* as you phrased it. All you need to worry about is a `true` value and a `false` value.

```
if(CheckValidity(ofd.FileName)) {

}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
if(CheckValidity(ofd.FileName) == true) {

}
else { // false condition

}
```

With a bool type you don't need to explicitly write out the comparison to true, and your original code  (without the explicit comparison) is more customary and is better style.

If you prefer to only check for false condition you can write:

```
if( ! CheckValidity(ofd.FileName) ) {

}
```

PS: Since you asked about *any bool return* the only time you'd ever have to consider a third return value would be using a nullable type (`bool?` or `Nullable<bool>`) which can also hold a null reference. You need not worry about that; the plain `bool` you used is a value type, and cannot be null.

To the downvoters of my initial answer, I explicitly wrote the comparison out to explain it to the OP.

I didn't feel the question was unclear. The excerpt that I quoted shows that the OP was confused by the semantics of `if(func())`, so I tried to clearly illustrate how a bool return type fits with an if/else statement. The key here is (1) the else{} block, and (2) the `== true` to illustrate that the code he wrote was already checking for true, and by adding an else he could handle the `false` condition. The part that I felt the OP misunderstood, fundamentally, was the very part I was trying to address with the style violation in my illustration. While I agree it is poor style, that was irrelevant.

To the OP, the reason `if(foo == true)` is bad style and strongly discouraged is it is (1) wordy/clumsy and (2) opens your logic up to the age old bug in languages that allow assignments within logical expressions; a common typo is `if(foo = true)` which is legal and often goes undetected if you aren't keeping an eye on compiler warnings. If you simply use `if(foo)` there is no chance of the typo.

Comment: `if(CheckValidity(ofd.FileName) == true` is the same as `if(CheckValidity(ofd.FileName)`

Comment: Yes, I wrote == true to illustrate to the OP who seemed a beginner.

Comment: It's all fun and games until == true ends in your production code and you want to kill it with fire.

Comment: There's no point teaching beginners a bad habit when you have an opportunity to teach them to understand instead.

Comment: Just for the record == false is just as annoying.

Comment: I agree with you, and actually upvoted. Perhaps the downvotes are more for answering a poor/unclear question?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET - Probably so; if I were a newcomer to SO I'd be mighty discouraged by such shallow voting. In 5 years this is the first time this has happened to me, but I am not in the business of judging the OP by the wording of his question, I'm just here to help people. Cheers.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET So you feel that the question is unclear, and don't understand what the question is actually asking, and yet you feel that this answer adequately answers that question that you don't understand?  Seems rather contradictory.

Comment: @Servy I feel it is adequately explaining the likely source of confusion for the OP. It is a much better version of my comment (that received 8 votes). Is the question terrible, yes. It can and likely should be deleted. The answer itself is pretty good in my opinion though. I've seen far worse get far better scores here.

Comment: I didn't feel the question was unclear. The excerpt that I quoted shows that the OP may not understand how the bool return type fits with an if/else statement. My answer was to show him the else{} block, and explicitly write the `== true` to illustrate that the first case was checking for true. The part that I felt the OP misunderstood, fundamentally, was the very part of his question that the downvoters either missed, or were so fixated on the style violation I used in my illustration, that they didn't care.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET - This answer may be my last on SO. I see the focus isn't on help, as much as writing good answers to good questions. Unfortunately, beginners often don't know how to write good questions.

Comment: @MelvinSmith An oft discussed topic on Meta to be sure. I actually kind of liked the SO academy idea... It would be a shame to see you go, but you are right, that is the focus. Part of the point of comments is to help write good questions, but it doesn't always work. The problem with this question was that he was *terrible* at pointing out the source of confusion, and just posted working code asking "How do I do this thing I already did?" Understandably, people are kind of peeved when you ask them that.

Comment: @MelvinSmith Reversed my downvote. This is much more constructive now than the original revision.